# Why does time.sleep() fail with cv2.VideoCapture() at the begining?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get a frame from the camera every each 3 seconds using `cv2.VideoCapture()` so I used `time.sleep()` to pause the execution, the code is here:

```
import cv2
import time
cnt = 0 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):
    time.sleep(3)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite('{}.png'.format(cnt),frame)
    cnt+=1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I got a stopwatch in front on the camera and save a frame each 3 seconds but I found that after the first frame there are other 4 frames that are wrongly saved so the saved images time is: 1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. Then how on earth that's happening?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but what happens if you set the framerate to 1/3 second at the start?

Comment: afaik either opencv or the camera itself can use buffers to improve image capturing behaviour, leading to this kind of effect.

Comment: imho the best way to solve it is to capture each frame without pauses and drop the unwanted ones yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that opencv is buffering multiple frames when you call `read()`. From a few other questions ([Get most recent frame from webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412057/get-most-recent-frame-from-webcam), http://answers.opencv.org/question/29957/highguivideocapture-buffer-introducing-lag/) it looks like 5 images are buffered, so you may need to `grab()` the extra 4 before continuing.